# How to add two navigationController in a viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I would like to add 2 navigationControllers in a viewcontroller. These 2 navigationController are totaly independent and are not linked. I would like to display these 2 navigationViewController one beside the other, like splitviewcontroller.

With childViewController, I succeed to add 2 viewControllers a the position and the size that I want. But when I try with navigationController, they take all the screen and display at the point (0,0). I try to change the frame of the navigationController but nothing changed.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT : Here is the code that I used to add childVC :

```
self.meetingsListViewController = [[MeetingsListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeetingsListViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navCalendar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:meetingsListViewController];
[self.navCalendar setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

self.meetingsListViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 54, self.view.frame.size.width/2-20, self.view.frame.size.height - 64);
self.navCalendar.view.frame = self.meetingsListViewController.view.frame;    
self.navCalendar.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

[self addChildViewController:meetingsListViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.meetingsListViewController.view];
[self.navCalendar didMoveToParentViewController:self];


self.listPlaylistViewController = [[ListPlaylistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListPlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navPlaylist = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:listPlaylistViewController];
[self.navPlaylist setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

self.listPlaylistViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2+10, 54, self.view.frame.size.width/2-20, self.view.frame.size.height - 64);
self.navPlaylist.view.frame = self.listPlaylistViewController.view.frame;
self.navPlaylist.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

[self addChildViewController:listPlaylistViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.listPlaylistViewController.view];
[self.navPlaylist didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: usally you should be able to modify the frame of the `UINavigationController`. Setting `navigationController.view.frame = ...` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The navigation controller take all the screen at the position (0,0).

Comment: hmm could you post the complete code you use to add the childvc and set it's frame?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you should do it in code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easy way is to add two container views to your controller's view in a storyboard, which will give you two embedded controllers. I think you should be able to select these embedded controllers and use the menu to embed them in a navigation controller. If that doesn't work, just delete those embedded controllers, drag out a navigation controller, add control drag from the container view to embed them.

**After Edit:**

If you want to do it in code, then there are several things wrong with what you've posted. The addChildViewController, addSubview, and didMoveToParentViewController calls should all be made to the navigation controllers, not the content controllers. There's also no need to set the frame of the content controllers, just set the frame of the navigation controllers directly:

```
self.meetingsListViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeetingsListViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navCalendar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.meetingsListViewController];

    self.navCalendar.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 54, self.view.frame.size.width/2-20, self.view.frame.size.height - 64);

    [self addChildViewController:self.navCalendar];
    [self.view addSubview:self.navCalendar.view];
    [self.navCalendar didMoveToParentViewController:self];


    self.listPlaylistViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListPlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navPlaylist = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.listPlaylistViewController];

    self.navPlaylist.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2+10, 54, self.view.frame.size.width/2-20, self.view.frame.size.height - 64);

    [self addChildViewController:self.navPlaylist];
    [self.view addSubview:self.navPlaylist.view];
    [self.navPlaylist didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```